# running vpython in a virtual environment

Tags: virtualenv, vpython

I am running python 3.9.9 in vs code and  Windows 10. When I run vpython in a standard(global) program my browser opens and the picture appears. When I run vpython in a virtual environment the browser opens but there is no picture, just a white screen and I do not get error messages.
Sample code:

from vpython import *
myBox = box(length=2,width=1,height=2, color=color.red)
while True:
pass

Answer (score 0):

You should first try restarting your computer, the same thing happened to me before, if that still doesn't work, maybe try reinstalling Visual Studio Code or `VPython`